# SQL Server : SUM() of multiple rows including where clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate

I have a table that looks something like the following :

```
  PropertyID     Amount     Type       EndDate
 --------------------------------------------
   1              100       RENT        null              
   1              50        WATER       null         
   1              60        ELEC        null        
   1              10        OTHER       null      
   2              70        RENT        null
   2              10        WATER       null
```

There will be multiple items billed to a property, also billed multiple times. For example RENT could be billed to property #1 12 times (over a year), however the only ones I'm interested for are those with ENDDATE of null (in otherwords, current)

I would like to achieve :

```
    PropertyId       Amount
  --------------------------       
      1                220
      2                80
```

I have tried to do something like this :

```
SELECT
   propertyId,
   SUM() as TOTAL_COSTS
FROM
   MyTable
```

However, in the SUM would I be forced to have multiple selects bringing back the current amount for each type of charge? I could see this becoming messy and I'm hoping for a much simpler solution

Any ideas?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This will bring back totals per property and type

```
SELECT  PropertyID,
        TYPE,
        SUM(Amount)
FROM    yourTable
GROUP BY    PropertyID,
            TYPE
```

This will bring back only active values

```
SELECT  PropertyID,
        TYPE,
        SUM(Amount)
FROM    yourTable
WHERE   EndDate IS NULL
GROUP BY    PropertyID,
            TYPE
```

and this will bring back totals for properties

```
SELECT  PropertyID,
        SUM(Amount)
FROM    yourTable
WHERE   EndDate IS NULL
GROUP BY    PropertyID
```

......

Comment: thanks! I went for the 3rd one, added some extra joins to other tables, and hey presto it all works! ;)

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   PropertyId,
   SUM(Amount) as TOTAL_COSTS
FROM
   MyTable
WHERE
   EndDate IS NULL
GROUP BY
   PropertyId
```

Comment: You forgot Amount inside SUM().

Answer (score 5):

you mean getiing sum(Amount of all types) for each property where EndDate is null:

```
SELECT propertyId, SUM(Amount) as TOTAL_COSTS
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE EndDate IS NULL
GROUP BY propertyId
```

Answer (score 4):

sounds like you want something like:

```
select PropertyID, SUM(Amount)
from MyTable
Where EndDate is null
Group by PropertyID
```

Answer (score 2):

The `WHERE` clause is always conceptually applied (the execution plan can do what it wants, obviously) prior to the `GROUP BY`.  It must come before the `GROUP BY` in the query, and acts as a filter **before** things are `SUM`med, which is how most of the answers here work.

You should also be aware of the optional `HAVING` clause which must come **after** the `GROUP BY`.  This can be used to filter on the resulting properties of groups after `GROUP`ing - for instance `HAVING SUM(Amount) > 0`

Answer (score 2):

Use a common table expression to add grand total row, `top 100` is required for `order by` to work.

```
With Detail as 
(
    SELECT  top 100 propertyId, SUM(Amount) as TOTAL_COSTS
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE EndDate IS NULL
    GROUP BY propertyId
    ORDER BY TOTAL_COSTS desc
)

Select * from Detail
Union all
Select ' Total ', sum(TOTAL_COSTS) from Detail
```