# Simple SUM Query needed for C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am a beginner programmer wanna ask about simple SUM query for C#. here is the case:

I have a table called `"revenue"`, and that table consist of 5 columns. they are `Bulan`, `Target`, `Realisasi`, `Target_YtD`, and `Realisasi_YtD`. for column `Bulan`, I manually inserted 12 data. they are `January`, `Februari`, `March`, and so on...

For column `Target` and `Realisasi` also I inserted data manually with `INT` data type.

Now, I wanna add up the `January's Target + February's Target + March's Target`, and then the value of that calculation is gonna fill March's Target_YtD.

Can somebody tell me the query of that? I hope anyone can help me this time, I really appreciate that. Thanks

Comment: Seems like a simple database statement, why do you need C# for it?

Comment: Have a read through this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: if you want sql query , you may look in to this, possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607720/sql-server-sum-of-multiple-rows-including-where-clauses

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
UPDATE 
SET Target_YtD =
  (SELECT SUM(Target) AS Total FROM revenue
  WHERE Bulan IN ('JAnuary', 'February', 'March')
)
WHERE Bulan = 'March'
```

Comment: youre almost there i guess. can i get your email anyway sir? i wanna ask about this problem deeper please.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you plan to calculate the colum at the time of input and save it to the database.  Usually calculated columns are not in and of themselves columns in databases,  but if that is what you are doing you can just use the c# concatenation function to populate that variable before doing your insert statement.  If you're only populating the sum upon output to a c# app,  same thing applies,  or you could do a sum in your sql code.  A few ways to get there,  just depends what you're trying to do.