# SQL Server Group By with Multiplication

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have this SQL Server 2005 Query

```
SELECT OI.BILL_NO,OI.ITEM_NAME,ODS.QUANTITY
FROM ORDER_ITEMS OI
INNER JOIN ORDER_ASSIGNMENTS OAS ON OI.BILL_NO=OAS.BILL_NO
INNER JOIN ORDERS ODS ON OI.BILL_NO = ODS.BILL_NO
INNER JOIN ORDERS OD ON OD.BILL_NO = OI.BILL_NO
WHERE OAS.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE= 'TO_STICHING' AND OAS.EMPLOYEE_NAME = 'AMIT'
```

I am getting this result :

[image]

Now my requirement is to to get the total Quantity of Every Distinct ITEM_NAME, Example:

```
CHURIDER           5    
CHURI PA           4
LACHA              1  
ASTRA              1
ASTRA LACHA DOUBLE 1
```

like this,all Distinct ITEM_NAME and their Total Quantity

Comment: Are you getting an error when you try to solve this with GROUP BY?   Post your query and results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server : SUM() of multiple rows including where clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607720/sql-server-sum-of-multiple-rows-including-where-clauses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a simple aggregation query with `group by`, and `sum()`:

```
SELECT OI.ITEM_NAME,sum(ODS.QUANTITY) as Quantity
FROM ORDER_ITEMS OI
INNER JOIN ORDER_ASSIGNMENTS OAS ON OI.BILL_NO=OAS.BILL_NO
INNER JOIN ORDERS ODS ON OI.BILL_NO = ODS.BILL_NO
INNER JOIN ORDERS OD ON OD.BILL_NO = OI.BILL_NO
WHERE OAS.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE= 'TO_STICHING' AND OAS.EMPLOYEE_NAME = 'AMIT'
group by OI.ITEM_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the sum of a column then group it by the name so

```
SELECT OI.BILL_NO,OI.ITEM_NAME,SUM(ODS.QUANTITY)
FROM ORDER_ITEMS OI
INNER JOIN ORDER_ASSIGNMENTS OAS ON OI.BILL_NO=OAS.BILL_NO
INNER JOIN ORDERS ODS ON OI.BILL_NO = ODS.BILL_NO
INNER JOIN ORDERS OD ON OD.BILL_NO = OI.BILL_NO
WHERE OAS.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE= 'TO_STICHING' AND OAS.EMPLOYEE_NAME = 'AMIT' 
GROUP BY OI.BILL_NO,OI.ITEM_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use aggregate function `SUM()`.

```
SELECT OI.BILL_NO,OI.ITEM_NAME, SUM(ODS.QUANTITY) AS Qty
```

`AS` used to add column name when displaying result because when you use aggregation function column name for that shows as `(no column name)`.

One last thing, you need to add other columns that you are selecting to `GROUP BY` clause because you are getting sum of each and every quantity so you need to group the other columns. [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998552/why-do-we-need-group-by-with-aggregate-functions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611897/group-by-aggregate-function-confusion-in-sql).

Add after `WHERE` clause

```
GROUP BY OI.BILL_NO,OI.ITEM_NAME
```